# How to sync two arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have 2 arrays of the same size that have separate types that I need to sync up.  One array is a list of doubles that I have sorted in descending order. The other is a list of chars 33-90 which correspond with their respective ASCII values. Prior to sorting the list of doubles the 2 arrays were lined up good but I cant sort the list of chars in the same way. What I need to happen is for the locations to be synced up, EX: `y[i] = ch[i];` but that command does not work.

```
void sortChars(int x[], double y[])
{
    int i;
    int largestIndex;
    int location;
    double temp;
    char ch[58];

    for (int i = 0; i < 58; i++)
        ch[i] = 33 + i;

    for (i = 0; i < 58; i++)
    {
        //Step a
        largestIndex = i;
        for (location = i + 1; location < 58; location++)
            if (x[location] > x[largestIndex])
                largestIndex = location;
            //Step b
        temp = x[largestIndex];
        x[largestIndex] = x[i];
        x[i] = temp;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 58; i++)
    {
        //Step a
        largestIndex = i;
        for (location = i + 1; location < 58; location++)
            if (y[location] > y[largestIndex])
                largestIndex = location;
            //Step b
        temp = y[largestIndex];
        y[largestIndex] = y[i];
        y[i] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 58; i++)
    {
        cout << ch[i] << " times used: " << left << setw(20) << x[i];
        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(6);
        cout << '\t' << "% of file: " << y[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

I have tried setting `ch[i] = y[i]`, I have tried using the selection sort from `y[]` and changing all the `y` parts in step `b` to `ch`. How would you go about matching these 2 arrays up? please try not to use `std::` type commands because all my projects use `using namespace std;`

Comment: ` y[i] = ch[i];` is bad because the types don't line up. Have you tried to mirror all operations that modify `y` on `ch`? Double the "Step b" for `y` and in one of the copies you replace every `y` by an `ch`.

Comment: I got it doing that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you meant to nest the 2nd and 3rd for loops in the first for loop. Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 58; i++)
{
    ch[i] = 33 + i;

  for (i = 0; i < 58; i++)
  {
    //Step a
    largestIndex = i;
    for (location = i + 1; location < 58; location++)
        if (x[location] > x[largestIndex])
            largestIndex = location;
        //Step b
    temp = x[largestIndex];
    x[largestIndex] = x[i];
    x[i] = temp;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 58; i++)
  {
    //Step a
    largestIndex = i;
    for (location = i + 1; location < 58; location++)
        if (y[location] > y[largestIndex])
            largestIndex = location;
        //Step b
    temp = y[largestIndex];
    y[largestIndex] = y[i];
    y[i] = temp;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 58; i++)
  {
    cout << ch[i] << " times used: " << left << setw(20) << x[i];
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(6);
    cout << '\t' << "% of file: " << y[i] << endl;
  }
}
```